# Friend class and all its descendants

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, friend

suppose that I have a class A with several subclasses (B, C, and D). I need B C and D to access some protected members from a class E. Is it possible to make B, C and D friends of E in a single hit without having to list them all?

I have tried with:

```
class E {

    friend class A;

    ...

};
```

But this doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html on why friendship isn't inherited, transitive, or reciprocal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can put protected accessor functions in A, and have A be a friend of E. That way, all derived classes of A can access the members of E via the accessor functions.